# Keep meteor running on amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, meteor, startup

I have a simple meteor app that I'm running on an Amazon EC2 server.  Everything is working great.  I start it manually with my user via `meteor` in the project directory.

However, what I would like is for this app to

1. Run on boot
2. Be immune to hangups

I try running it via `nohup meteor &`, but when I try to log out of the EC2 instance, I get the "You have running jobs" message.  Continuing to log out stops the app.

How can I get the app to start on startup and stay up (unless it crashes for some reason)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) and use a start script.

```
$ npm install -g forever
```

I have several scripts for managing my production environment - the start script looks something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

forever stopall

export MAIL_URL=...
export MONGO_URL=...
export MONGO_OPLOG_URL=...
export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL=...
forever start /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/bundle/main.js

exit 0
```

Conveniently, it will also append to a log file in `~/.forever` which will show any errors encountered while running your app. You can get the location of the log file and other stats about your app with:

```
$ forever list
```

To get your app to start on startup, you'd need to do something appropriate for your flavor of linux. You can maybe just put the start script in `/etc/rc.local`. For ubuntu see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871997/how-can-i-run-my-own-script-at-every-bootup).

Also note you **really** should be bundling your app if using it in production. See [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316344/meteor-vs-meteor-bundle-for-production/) for more details on the differences.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  I'm using Amazon Linux, not Ubuntu.  I bundled it, but it won't start because it's missing `fibers`.  I cd to `bundle/server` and run `npm install --nodedir=/usr/local/bin fibers`, but I get `gyp: /usr/local/bin/common.gypi not found`.  Any ideas?

Comment: 1) see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327088/meteor-bundle-fails-because-fibers-node-is-missing) question. 2) what version of node are you running?

Comment: It's recommended that you use the node versions specified in the [meteor history](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md) for your particular release. Though, I suspect that may not be the issue here. Do a search for "node error common.gypi" and you will get several answers including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021884/node-expat-install-error-on-ubuntu-vm).

Answer (score 1):

I am using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) on Ubuntu server which you should be able to easily install on Amazon linux.

This is roughly my `/etc/init/myapp.conf`:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
    export HOME="/home/deploy"
    export NODE_ENV="production"
    export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myappdb"
    export ROOT_URL=http://localhost
    export MAIL_URL=smtp://localhost:25
    export METEOR_SETTINGS='{"somesetting":true}'

    cd /var/www/myapp/bundle/
    exec sudo -u deploy PORT=3000 /usr/bin/node main.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
end script
```

I can then manually start and stop `myapp` like this:

```
sudo start myapp
sudo stop myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this package solves your problem: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

which seems to use `forever`: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Comment: It seems like `mup` was designed to only work for Ubuntu, but I'm running Amazon Linux