# Run Meteor as a Daemon process

Tags: linux, meteor, daemon

I've just setup a Linux CentOS server to run a Meteor application.

The first problem I come across now is starting the meteor process as a Daemon, so it's running in background and I can exit my SSH session.. When starting with `meteor --production` I can't.

When using Ruby on Rails I could just start with `rails s -d -p 80` and exit.

I found out that an app called screen and `echo "meteor --production" | at` are options, but I do not have the `at` command installed, and installing an app just for running it in background seems like a weird choice.

Do I really need to install `screen` or `at`? Are there any other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep meteor running on amazon EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447818/keep-meteor-running-on-amazon-ec2)

Comment: have you tried `meteor --production &` ? The `&` at the end puts the job into the background.

Comment: The comment given by @ChristianFritz is misleading; `--production` is still development mode; just that the files are minified. You need to bundle Meteor, and run it as a daemon you would any node process.

Comment: @AndrewMao: that's sort of besides the point. While I agree with you in terms of bundling vs. `--production`, the OP specifically asked about it, and is really struggling with a linux issue of keeping processes started in a shell alive. This isn't about bundling or not.

Comment: @ChristianFritz backgrounding a process will cause it to exit when you quit the shell too, unless you `disown` in bash, for example. I would also suggest for the OP to use screen.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Though that would be a solution for me, because it's not really a problem it run in dev mode, it won't work, when I quit my shell the process is still stopped.

Comment: @AndrewMao Screen is indeed a solution, also I tried tmux, but I couldn't get that to work.. After all my research I came to the conclusion that bundling is indeed a better option. After bundling I will use `pm2` to run it, it has lot's of great and usable extra functions too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) creates a daemon with these features:

- Auto-Restart if the app crashed (using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever))
- Auto-Start after the server reboot (using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/))

Answer (score 1):

Turns out theres no simple way to run an unbundled Meteor-app. There is always going to be other software involved like `screen`, `tmux` or `at`.

The duplicate of this question explains a lot about the process of running your app after it's bundled.

One piece of software that isn't mentioned there is `pm2`. I didn't use it yet, just installed it, but it seems like a really great tool to start the app in background and keep it running continuously.

Answer (score 0):

The Demeteorizer project may be a good option for you. It converts a Meteor project into a standard Node.js project.

You can get it at https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following shell command

```
$ ROOT_URL="http://yourserver.com" nohup meteor --production -p 8085 >meteor.log 2>meteor.error.log &
```

Replace 8085 with the port that you want to run it on.
If you are running your own mongo instance and do not want to use meteor's bundled mongo, you can also add the MONGO_URL="mongodb://yourserver:port/"