# How I deploy my Meteor app to the internet from my Ubuntu Azure VM?

Tags: azure, deployment, meteor, cloud, virtual-machine

I have set up a VM on Azure and on it I built a Meteor app which I can run on the VM itself using localhost:3000

Now I want to deploy it online. I have a domain name and a BizSpark account.

What I have tried:

1) Just accessing the VM through its IP address and specifying port 3000, i.e. typing into my browser address: xxx.xxx.xx.x:3000 where the xs are my server address

2) Using my cloudapp address, i.e myapp.cloudapp.net

Neither of these work, how do I proceed to have my app, which is a Telescope forum, to run on my domain name?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not an expert in deploying apps, I strongly recommend using [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). It will take care of all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I deploy it using the readme on a linux box, it's pretty straight forward once you completed the meteor build. it requires nodejs and mongo installed on the server that will old you meteor app.

You can also simply use 'meteor deploy yourapp' and redirect your domain to yourapp.meteor.com
Or you can try tu use MUP (my next challenge).

My very favorite source for this is a French guy who blogs about Meteor in English :
https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your VM's endpoint settings on https://manage.windowsazure.com/? Adding a rule there should allow anyone to connect to `<vm-dns-name>.cloudapp.net:<public-port>`.
That's the DNS name, not the VM name. My Meteor app didn't need the direct server return feature.

If you can connect remotely while running it from a shell, [demonize meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141373/run-meteor-as-a-daemon-process) to keep it running after you disconnect the shell. [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) provides these features:

- Auto-Restart if the app crashed (using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever))
- Auto-Start after the server reboot (using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/))