# Should i use the Mongo DB that comes with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When creating a Meteor app., Mongo is installed by default and runs automatically when I run my app. In the past, with other non-Meteor apps, I have always tried to place my app code files and database on separate servers to ensure that I can scale them independently. It feels as though this default Mongo install is a convenient way simply for Meteor to use a database out-of-the box, just to get you going. Thinking ahead, I want my app to scale, so should I start thinking about using a Mongo instance on separate server and, if so, what process do I go through to detach this default Mongo instance from my Meteor app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of mongodb that comes with meteor is only for use when developing your app. In a production environment, you should either install your own mongo instance or use a service.

I strongly recommend using [compose.io](https://www.compose.io/mongodb/) in production. We've had a really good experience with them and the most basic deployment comes with access to the [oplog](https://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-oplog-and-meteor.html) which is critical for scaling your app.

Either way, in production you will provide two URLs to your app via environment variables:

- MONGO_URL
- MONGO_OPLOG_URL (this is optional but strongly recommended)

If you go with compose, here is [the guide](https://blog.compose.io/meteor-and-compose-a-beginners-guide-to-using-them-together/) for integrating with meteor.

Comment: If setting the environment variable, I take it this will mean that any other apps running on the app server will only be able to connect to the same Mongo instance defined by this variable? Can I use, for example: var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/my-database"); in my Meteor application to switch between Mongo servers?

Comment: That would be true if you were setting the env vars globally (.bashrc, .profile, etc). The recommended way is to export the variables in a script which then starts the app so they don't leak into the outer environment. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447818/keep-meteor-running-on-amazon-ec2) for more details. No, please don't set the connection values in the code.

Comment: ... but what if I wanted to switch between two Mongo instances in my app?

Comment: While it's running? I'd recommend reading [this](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/). You really don't want to add things that look like production credentials to your code.